# Can I serve .obj files as Django static files?

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I'm looking to do a bit of 3D modeling on my site and I'm trying to serve the requisite object (.obj) and material (.mtl) files via Django.  When I put them into my static directory and run collectstatic, the .mtl files are found and collected just fine, but the .obj files are completely ignored.

Is there any way around this?  Is there somewhere Django bans certain file types for static collection, and can that be overwritten?  Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Collectstic ignores files with filename matching any pattern in list ['CVS', '*~', '.*']. *.obj does not match any of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, all - figured this out. Was a Git issue - I think I had some global .gitignore file that was ignoring .obj files, so I just created a new blank one.  Closing issue.